# SQFLite: How to get data when field value is json_encode?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I have data like this when using query `final result = await db.query(tablePelajaran); print(result)` .

> Note: semester value is object i convert to json using json.encode()

```
[{id_pelajaran: 1, name_pelajaran: pelajran test, semester: {"id_semester":1,"name_semester":"Semester I"}, hari: [{"id_day":1,"name_day":"Senin","code_color":4294013189},{"id_day":2,"name_day":"Selasa","code_color":4291891529},{"id_day":3,"name_day":"Rabu","code_color":4284879090},{"id_day":4,"name_day":"Kamis","code_color":4279930851}], dosen: }, {id_pelajaran: 2, name_pelajaran: Another Pelajaran, semester: {"id_semester":2,"name_semester":"Semester II"}, hari: [{"id_day":1,"name_day":"Senin","code_color":4294013189},{"id_day":5,"name_day":"Jumat","code_color":4290904315}], dosen: }]
```

But now i want show only data when **semester = 1** then i write query like this :

```
    final db = await database();
    final result = await db.rawQuery(
      'SELECT * FROM $tablePelajaran WHERE semester = ? ',
      [1],
    );
    print(result);
```

But the result always null , i expected data with **id_semester = 1** will show . 
 How can i access **id_semester** when this id is inside json.encode. I can't do json.decode() because i dont have **semester** data when query.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i access id_semester when this id is inside json.encode. I can't do json.decode() because i dont have semester data when query.

You should split the semester object into 2 other columns to access their values. Since sqflite is a structural database, it only allows fetching value at column level, not possible to go deeper than that. Then you only need to query the semeter_id column value:

```
final result = await db.rawQuery(
  'SELECT * FROM $tablePelajaran WHERE semester_id = ? ',
  [1],
);
```

One other solution if you're not allowed to modify the database structure, is to fetch all data, then parse it to a list of object

```
final pelajarans = List<Pelajaran>.from(data.map((rawPelajaran)=>Pelajaran.fromJson(rawPelajaran));
```

where rawPelajaran is each item inside the array you query from database.

Then from here you filter the data:

```
var _result = pelajarans.where((e) => e.semesterId == 1).toList;
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Can you give simple example  ? in other word , i can't access field when is json.encode ?

Comment: @ZeffryReynando I've just updated my answer in case you aren't allowed to modify the database structure

Comment: But i actually avoid to show all data then filter it just to get 1 data.  Because when i have  let's say 300 data then i want show data with id 100 , i must query all data then filter using dart list.

Comment: @ZeffryReynando You can query all data once then store it in a variable/ local storage for later usage. Else the only other way is to create another `semester` table to link with the original table, or add 2 more column for semester_id and name_semester.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your json `semester` value is actually String type. That's why when you want to get the value of `id_semester` it gives you null value. To get the value of `id_semester` you need to convert String to map. For that you can use `jsonDecode`. Here is an example:

```
final result = await db.query(tablePelajaran);
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(result[0]['semester']);
print(map['id_semester']);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data= await _db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tablePelajaran where json_extract($tablePelajaran.semester,"\$.id_semester") =?',[1]);
```

> By using json_extract you can access any json inside any column...